# What is the English name for the "Исламский джихад - Джамаат моджахедов" organization?

Tags: russia, terrorism

[Russia's list of designated terrorist organizations](http://nak.fsb.ru/nac/ter_org.htm) contains a list of names that are easily identifiable, except this one that I can't identify:

> Исламский джихад - Джамаат моджахедов

I could find some info about it in Russian, but not in English.

How is this organization known as in the English-speaking world?

[Google Translate says](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://nak.fsb.ru/nac/ter_org.htm) "Islamic Jihad - Jamaat Mujahideen".

Comment: Google (http://www.google.com/search?q=Jamaat+Mujahideen&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1&safe=active) tells me that's a Bengali terrorist group.

Answer (score 4):

[A 2010 FIDH monograph](http://www.fidh.org/IMG/pdf/Russian_society_under_control.pdf) lists the group as one Islamic Jihad (''Mujahedeen Jamaat''), linked to the Muslim Brotherhood movement, which would identify it with the Islamic Jihad Movement in Palestine, usually referred to as the **Palestinian Islamic Jihad** (PIJ) in the West. The [Russian Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B4) offers *Harakat al-Jihad al-Islami fi Filastin* and *Jamaat Mujahideen* as alternative names, which seems to fit, and at least once source identified PIJ as the group banned along with Jund ash Sham in 2006.

I'm not entirely satisfied with this answer, however. Jihad, Jama'at, and Mujahideen are all extremely common words for naming (and nicknaming and aliasing) such groups, and [other sources](http://www.start.umd.edu/start/data_collections/tops/terrorist_organization_profile.asp?id=82) state that PIJ is *not* a Russia-designated terrorist organization. I would think the activities of the **Islamic Jihad Union (IJU)**, a splinter group of the Islamic Movement of Uzbekistan (formerly the Islamic Jihad Group), would make it a candidate, but the IMU is already listed on its own, and I cannot say as to whether the new group is recognized as independent of it.

Comment: +1, especially for the second paragraph. The name sounds too vague to be able to identify uniquely without extra data (area of operations etc...)